# Making a .NET Windows application show-up on keystroke

Tags: .net, keyboard, desktop-application, keystroke

My application resides mostly on the system tray on minimize. I'd like the user to be able to hit a keystroke (like ALT+SHIFT etc.) and it shows up on the screen (sort of like Launchy, if you've used it; or the Google search bar).

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: I wanted know about this but always forgot ask. Great question :)

Answer (score 2):

You want the SetWindowsHookEx Windows API call. There is some details on using it in this CodeProject article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/CSLLKeyboard.aspx

There is also some useful advice about what will and won't work and what tricky issues lurk around SetWindowsHookEx and .NET here:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetWindowsHookEx

Answer (score 2):

The [Managed Windows API](http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/) has a Hotkey class that wraps the low-level hooking you want. Incredibly easy to use.

Comment: It's pretty foolproof. You make a Hotkey instance, set the keystrokes, enable it and you're receiving events.